# How do I title case a sentence in javascript using simple substring function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to title case a string which capitalizes only the first character in each word.
I tried doing it using the following code. This is what I've done till now.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
 var lowstr = str.toUpperCase();
  var array=lowstr.split(' ');
  var arr;
  var arr1;
   for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
      arr1=array[i].substring(0,1); 
      
      for(var j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)
        {
      arr=array[j].substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }
      arr=arr1.concat(arr);     
    }
        array.join(" ");
  return array;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: It's great that you've got that, but what is your problem?

Comment: The code isn't working. I can't seem to rectify the error.   The error's showing up as "array[j] is undefined". I thought the variable j will act as the index.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as if you're trying to do too much in your `titleCase` function. I would take a slightly different approach that follows **Single Responsibility Principle** a little more closely.

**I would have...**

1. A function to titleCase a single word.
2. A function that titleCases each word in a sentence.

### Example:

```
function titleCaseSingleWord(word) {

    if (word.length === 0) {
        return "";
    }

    var result = word[0].toUpperCase();
    for (var i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
        result += word[i].toLowerCase();
    }

    return result;
}

function titleCaseSentence(sentence) {
    var titleCasedWords = [];

    var words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i];
        var titleCasedWord = titleCaseSingleWord(word);
        titleCasedWords.push(titleCasedWord);
    }

    return titleCasedWords.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCaseSentence("im a liTTLE teapot"));
// "Im A Little Teapot"
```

### Reasoning Behind Multiple Functions:

- It makes it easier to test each individual function and find the errors quicker. It also helps to keep your functions shallow.

### Notes:

- These functions are a little bit messy and could do with some refactoring, but I'll leave that to you as a mini exercise.
- Also, one could go further and say that `titleCaseSentence` is both splitting the words *and* titleCasing them, so it should be split up further. That's entirely up to you whether you want to do that or not.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions solution to the problem:

```js
console.log(
//Base string
"i'm a little tea pot"
//Enforce lowercase
  .toLowerCase()
  //Regular expression replace with uppercase
  .replace(
    /(\s+.)|^\w/ig,
    function(v) {
      return v.toUpperCase();
    })
);
```

Comment: This is NICE! I was toying with this implementation and wondering how to capitalize the match of a regex. Wasn't aware a callback could be used with replace. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

you set them all to uppercase, then find the letters that are supposed to be lower case.

What I'd do is the opposite. I'd start off the same, with

`arr = str.split(" ")`

but then you can go

`for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++)`

`arr[x].substring(0,1) = arr[x].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()`

and then join them back up.

Can't see why you'd need a nested loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to forgo substring and consider a more 'functional' approach, try this.

```
String.prototype.titleCase = function() {
    t = this.toLower().split(' ').map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+word.slice(1)).join(' ');
    return t;
}
```

Since I've declared the function on the String.prototype, you can use it thus:

```
"This is a title".titleCase() // >> "This Is A Title"
```

which may not be 100% the way newspaper editors would have it, but it does what you seem to want it to do. Let me know if you need an explanation.

Also, if you want a function to use thus: `TitleCase("some sentence here")` you can easily refactor the code.  Let me know if you need further explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Check This Out..

```
function titleCase(str) {

 var arr=str.split('');
 var array=[];

for(var x=0;x<arr.length;x++)
   { if(x==0){
  array[x]=arr[x].toUpperCase();
  x++;
      }

 array[x]=arr[x].toLowerCase();

  if(arr[x]==' ')
    {
      array[x+1]=arr[x+1].toUpperCase();
      x++;
    }
}
var st=array.join('');
return st;
 }

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```